# response de nodejs no concuerda con el resultado de la peticion ajax usando formidable

Tags: ajax, json, nodejs, angular

Hola buenas estoy subiendo un fichero a nodejs con el modulo formidable y todo va bien , el fichero se guarda en el directorio que he indicado y tal, pero el response que recibo en la pagina me dice que **no se ha encontrado ningun fichero para subir** pero **si** que se sube, a continuacion dejo el codigo:

**Funcion de nodejs que sube el fichero**

```
router.post('/uploadImage', (request, response) => {
    const form = new formidable.IncomingForm()
    const address = path.dirname(__filename).split('/')
    address.pop()

    form.uploadDir = `BACKEND/imagenes/`; //path donde guardaras la imagines
    form.keepExtensions = true; //mantener las extensiones
    form.maxFieldsSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; //10MB
    form.multiples = true; //multiples archivos

    form.parse(request, (err, fields, files) => {
        if (err) {
            response.json({
                message: 'error al subir la imagen',
                data: []
            })
        }

        const { upload } = files //Hacemos Destructuring, por lo que equivale a 'const upload = files.upload'
        let data

        if (upload) { //Si existe archivo subido o no
            let filesPath

            if (Array.isArray(upload)) { //Si se han subido mas de un archivo, es decir, si es un Array de archivos
                filesPath = upload.map(file => file.path)
            } else {
                filesPath = upload.path
            }

            data = {
                message: 'imagen subida correctamente !!',
                data: filesPath, //Devolvemos una o la lista de rutas de los archivos
                numImagenes: upload.length //Devolvemos la cantidad de archivos
            }
        } else {
            data = {
                message: 'No hay ninguna imagen seleccionada para subir .. ',
                data: [],
                numImagenes: 0
            }
        }

        response.json(data)
    })
})
```

**Formulario de prueba Angular**

```
  <div class="pruebaSubirArchivo"  style="border: solid">
    <form #formImage="ngForm" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="POST" ngForm>


      <div>
        <input  type="file" placeholder="imagencita"  (change)="onFileSelected($event)"
        name="imagencita">
      </div>


      <div>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" > Enviar Imagen</button>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
```

**Funcion Typescript de frontend que sube imagen**

```
 onFileSelected(event) {
    this.selectedFile = <File>event.target.files[0];
    //console.log(this.selectedFile);

    //this.empleado_nuevo.imagen_perfil = this.selectedFile.name;
    const fd = new FormData();
    let url = 'http://localhost:3000/uploadImage';

    fd.append('image', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
    this.http.post(url, fd).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
      });

    //console.log(this.empleado_nuevo.imagen_perfil);
  }
```

**Console del navegador (Chrome)**

```
    {message: "No hay ninguna imagen seleccionada para subir .. ", data: Array(0), numImagenes: 0}
data: []
message: "No hay ninguna imagen seleccionada para subir .. "
numImagenes: 0
__proto__: Object
```

**Reitero que funciona** solo que no recibo el response adecuado en el explorado

Comment: Mira que te devuelve el files proque por alguna razón al asignarselo a la constatnte upload este te da false.

Comment: cierto he hecho un console.log y me dice `undefined` pero en cambio funciona la subida

Comment: Eso es que la subida lo hace antes de entrar aquí

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Respuesta Inicial (Errónea)

Estás poniendo que tu formulario debe ser procesado como múltiple, es decir que puede recibir muchos archivos

```
     form.multiples = true; //multiples archivos
```

[Según la documentación:](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable)

> If this option is enabled, when you call `form.parse`, the `files`
>   argument will contain arrays of files for inputs which submit multiple
>   files using the HTML5 multiple attribute.

Esto significa que `files` no es un objeto sino un array de objetos de tipo `file` y por añadidura

```
  const {upload} = files;
```

Es la destructuración de un array, que no tiene propiedad `upload`.

## Respuesta Corregida

Probándolo en mi local, efectivamente como escribió el OP los archivos están dentro de una propiedad. Si esta propiedad fuese `upload` entonces

```
  const {upload} = files;
```

Sería **correcto**  y puede ser un objeto de tipo `File` o un array de éstos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Sin embargo** el nombre de la propiedad `upload` no es fijo. Está determinado por el nombre del input. De manera que si el OP puso:

```
 <input type="file" name="imagencita">
```

Los archivos están en `files.imagencita`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y por lo mismo, al hacer la comprobación

```
 if (upload) {
    ...
 } else {
    // no hay archivos para subir
 }
```

Efectivamente no existe la propiedad `upload`.

**Haciendo el flujo completo para este caso:**

Como sabemos que el campo se llama `imagencita`,  la ruta quedaría más o menos así:

```
router.post('/uploadImage', (req, res) => {
    const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    /* configuracion de form */

    form.uploadDir = path.resolve(`${__dirname}/../imagenes/`); //path donde guardaras la img
    form.keepExtensions = true; //mantener las extensiones
    form.maxFieldsSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; //10MB
    form.multiples = true; //multiples archivos

    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
        let data, filesPath, numImagenes;
        if (err) {
            data = {
                message: err.message
            };
        } else if (!files || !files.imagencita) {
            data = {
                message: 'No hay ninguna imagen seleccionada para subir .. ',
                data: [],
                numImagenes: 0
            };
        } else {
            const {imagencita} = files;

            if (Array.isArray(imagencita)) {
                //Si se han subido mas de un archivo, es decir, si es un Array de archivos
                numImagenes = imagencita.length;
                filesPath = imagencita.map(file => file.path);
            } else {
                numImagenes = 1;
                filesPath = imagencita.path;
            }

            data = {
                message: 'imagen subida correctamente !!',
                data: filesPath, //Devolvemos una o la lista de rutas de los archivos
                numImagenes //Devolvemos la cantidad de archivos
            };
        }

        res.json(data);
    });
});
```

Si te fijas, ocupé un planteamiento "fail early" para evitar anidar ifs:

1. Si hay error, la respuesta es el mensaje de error
2. Si no hay error pero no hay files o files no tiene la propiedad `imagencita` la respuesta es que no hay archivos subidos
3. Pasadas las dos anteriores, significa que sí hay archivos

Comment: De acuerdo, tengo una duda al respecto, como se entonces si hubo un error en la subida ? ya que no tendria algo como `if(error){tal cosa}`

Comment: Amigo @joseangel, una pregunta cada vez. Si esta respuesta te resolvió el problema que planteas, deberías considerar el *aceptarla* (símbolo del *check*, a la izquierda). Si tienes nuevas dudas, sientete libre de publicar otra pregunta :-)

Comment: estaba esperando que me respondiese a mi pregunta para asegurarme antes de validar algo en lo que no creo, pero muchas gracias

Comment: Hice la prueba en mi local y tienes razón, los archivos están dentro de una propiedad, pero esa propiedad se llama como tu input, "imagencita"

Comment: @amenadiel como podria , a partir de esto, modificar los nombres de subidas de los archivos a i gusto? cual es la propiedad

Comment: la propiedad es el atributo `name` de tu input de tipo `file`